# Core Data:after add new date, how to refresh data to display

Tags: ios, core-data

There are 3 ViewController:
[image]

The `managedObjectContext` of `rootViewController` reference the `managedObjectContext` in `AppDelegate`; the `managedObjectContext` of `displayViewController` and the `managedObjectContext` of `manageDataViewController` reference the `managedObjectContext` of `rootViewController`.

`DisplayViewController'view` displays some data in some controls.

Now, after add new data, `DisplayViewController'view` has not changed, unless restart the app.

What's why?

Comment: Do you have any code that updates that view? Changing data in a managed object context does not automatically update views.

Comment: In 'viewWillAppear' method, every time. use 'NSFetchRequest' to fetch result and to draw in 'DisplayViewController'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a view to auto-update you have two options. The easies way would be to add an observer to your managed object context like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                  selector:@selector(<#Selector name#>)
                                  name: NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
                                  object:<#A managed object context#>];
```

You will then get a call back any time the managed object context changes. Its up to you to filter out the relevant changes.

You can also use an NSFetchedResultsController but they are really geared towards UITableViews and not much else.